# How do i save the intervals from .qcut()?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, cut

I was told to use .qcut() to find the value at each percentile given.
The return value was a list identical interval values. How do i save the interval values to each specific percentile?

```
[In] pd.qcut(df['A'], 4)
[Out] 2732426    (35.881, 1363.92]
824448     (35.881, 1363.92]
3450257    (35.881, 1363.92]
1207627    (35.881, 1363.92]
                 ...        
2561280      (-0.001, 4.836]
1377013      (-0.001, 4.836]
3072978      (-0.001, 4.836]
Name: A, Length: 289224, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 4.836] < (4.836, 14.139] < 
(14.139, 35.881] < (35.881, 1363.92]]
```

Expected results should be like:

```
Quantiles       25%        50%         75%          100%
Values          4.836      14.139      35.881       1363.92
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`cat.categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html) with [`IntervalIndex.right`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.right.html), last pass it to DataFrame constructor:

```
a = pd.qcut(df['A'], 4).cat.categories.right

df1 = pd.DataFrame([a], columns=['25%','50%','75%','100%'])
```

Comment: Why is the value obtained from a 

"Float64Index([4.313, 10.689, 26.348, 2326.586], dtype='float64')"

different from the interval tails? 
"Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 4.836] < (4.836, 14.139] < 
(14.139, 35.881] < (35.881, 1363.92]] "

Which is the accurate one though?

Comment: It is weird, what is `pd.qcut(df['A'], 4).cat.categories` ?

Comment: Hi, i figured out and it works. But i have another question! How do i loop it through dataframe of ['A', 'B', 'C'] so i can add subsequent rows to my table, with the same columns?